# Adding a profile image in django is not working

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to add profile image to my page, but for some reason "my image" text is shown instead of a image.

I do not have any clue about what is wrong in my code, i jave read trough multiple tutorials and they all tells me to do this way. I have a folder "media" in my root directory and inside that i have folder "profile_pics".

I have added these to settings.py

```py
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

these to urls.py

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my html

```html
{% load static %}
{%block content%}
    <div class="content-section">
        <div class="media">
            <img src="{% static "profile_pics/default.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
{%endblock content%}
```

models.py

```py
class profiili(models.Model):
   user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   kuva=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

Comment: try <img src="{% static 'profile_pics/default.jpg' %}"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this if you have successfully uploaded your image  throughOnetoOne relation between User and Profiili model

```
     div class="content-section">
             <div class="media">
                 <img src="{{user.profiili.kuva.url}}" alt="My i mage"/>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }} 
            </h2>
            <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{% static %}` tag works only for `STATIC_URL`. To get media files you should use `{% get_media_prefix %}`

Like:

```
{% load static %}
{% get_media_prefix as MEDIA_PREFIX %}
<img src="{{ MEDIA_PREFIX }}profile_pics/default.jpg" alt="My image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use direct link of your image. django devlopment server will serve it in only debug = True. 
put this in your image tag.

src="/profile_pics/default.jpg" alt="My Image"

Answer (score 0):

`{% get_media_prefix as MEDIA %}` won't work. `MEDIA` seems to be some kind of a reserve word. `{% get_media_prefix as MEDIA_URL %}` or some other word will work.

Also you will need to add this code inside the `{% block content %}` block. Otherwise it will not work. By that I mean you will not be able to access `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` inside the content block.